# Attach created Word doc to Outlook Message

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-word

I have read numerous responses that are close to what I am looking for, but each time it doesn't work in my code.

This should be a pretty basic question, but I am hoping someone can look at this and see my error quickly.

I am using Excel to create a Word Doc which is then saved on the users Desktop in a folder named with the current date.

Everything works perfectly, but now all I am trying to do is add to the Word doc the name of the string "IRN" which is a cell in the Excel worksheet.

I also need to attach the created Word doc to an Outlook message.

I will only include the intro and end of my code as the body should not matter.

```
Sub TDOutlook()

Dim TD As Word.Application
Dim Doc As Word.Document
Dim path As String
Dim filename As String
Dim StudentName As String
Dim StudentAddress1 As String
Dim City As String
Dim MrMrs As String
Dim StudentLast As String
Dim IRN As String
Dim CourseReq As String
Dim CourseName As String
Dim CourseStart As String
Dim Cost As String
Dim Deferred As String
Dim Graphic As String
Dim Footer1 As Word.Range
Dim Body As Word.Paragraph
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem

path = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\" & Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy")
    On Error Resume Next
    MkDir path
    On Error GoTo 0

'Outlook
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objOutlookMsg = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

objOutlookMsg.SentOnBehalfOfName = "bbb@ppp.edu"
objOutlookMsg.Subject = "FinServ-TD"
objOutlookMsg.HTMLBody = "Testing this macro" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf


'Display Outlook
objOutlookMsg.Display

'Opens Word
Set TD = CreateObject("Word.Application")

'Displays the document
TD.Visible = False

'Add New Document
Set Doc = TD.Documents.Add

filename = path & "\TD" '& IRN
Doc.SaveAs filename

'Attach Word to Outlook
objOutlookMsg.Attachments.Add Doc.filename    <----This is broken

Doc.Close

TD.Quit

'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Try filename = path & "TD" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Text - assuming the IRN is in cell A1

Comment: See How to save it using cell value http://stackoverflow.com/a/30393989/4539709

Comment: Thank you Om3r, I didn't include it in my text but the variable IRN was set to that specific cell in the sheet but it wouldn't include it in the filename for some reason, but linking directly to the cell like you indicated worked perfectly. Do you know how I can add the word doc as an attachment to my open Outlook email by chance?

Comment: I have tried it with Doc.filename and filename, neither work. I get an error that states "Cannot find this file. Verify the path and file name are correct"

Comment: Ok sounds good. No unfortunately that file name or directory name is not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everything works perfectly, but now all I am trying to do is add to the Word doc the name of the string "IRN" which is a cell in the Excel worksheet.

To get the Cell Value Try this

**`FileName = Path & "\TD" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Text & ".docx"`**

> I also need to attach the created Word doc to an Outlook message.

To attached saved file, change this

**`objOutlookMsg.Attachments.Add Doc.filename`** To this 
**`ObjOutlookMsg.Attachments.Add (FileName)`**

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I was able to get both aspects working. Thank you for all of your help Om3r!