# Save as PDF and Excel 2016 Copy In Folder and Filename created from Cell Value

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I'm working with Excel 2016, I have created a Template with a main Sheet(G-Card) and the following 3 sheets get the information from the first sheet.

I have a Macro that allows me to save all 4 sheets into PDF creating a Folder in a specific location and saving it under that folder using cell values. I have also manage to save the workbook as a copy under the same filename in the same folder but it says that it is not compatible or extension error.

The only extension that seems to work is .xlm. I need to be able to save the template as a PDF and as an Excel file in the same folder including the macro in the 2016 version. Help please.. here is my code:

```
Sub NewFolder_SaveasPDF_CLICK()  

Dim strFilename As String 

Dim FldrName As String
On Error Resume Next

Set rngRANGE = Worksheets("G-Card").Range("U3")

FldrName = Worksheets("G-Card").Range("O4").Value

strFilename = rngRANGE.Value & " "  

MkDir "Q:\Green Cards & Acknowledgement\Green Cards & Acknowledgement\2017 Orders\" & FldrName

Sheets(Array("G-Card", "P-AKG", "W-AKG", "Y-AKG")).Select Sheets("G-Card").Activate

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _ 
"Q:\Green Cards & Acknowledgement\Green Cards & Acknowledgement\2017 Orders\" & FldrName & "\" & strFilename & Worksheets("G-Card").Range("O4").Value & ".pdf" _ 
, QUALITY:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True _

Dim ExcelWork As String  

ExcelWork = strFilename & FldrName

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="Q:\Green Cards & Acknowledgement\Green Cards & Acknowledgement\2017 Orders\" & FldrName & "\" & ExcelWork & ".xlm", _ 
FileFormat:=xlNormal, Password:="", _ 
WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False  

End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with the copy part? I understand that you exported your file as a PDF at some point, but where is the problem in the following part?

Comment: when it saves as an Excel File it keeps asking for compatible error and when I open the Excel copy it keeps saying there is an error with the format do I want to proceed anyways?

Comment: This is what comes up every time I open the Excel copy: The file format and extension of X don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyways?

Comment: So you get no issues, when you save the excel file with an .xlsm ending?

Comment: try using FileFormat:=52 instead of Fileformat:=xlNormal

Comment: FileFormat:=52 work for the compatible part but I am still getting the same pop up box when I open the file.

Comment: The .xlsm ending didnt work before but I will try with the new fileformat

Comment: Marco Getrost, It worked! using the .xlsm and FileFormat:=52 did the trick! Thank you so much!

Comment: `".xlm"` ????? or you mean `xlsm`?  see quick save as - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30393659/how-do-i-name-a-spreadsheet-automatically-by-referencing-two-cells/30393989#30393989