# How can I export, using VBA, specific sheets in my main workbook, to a new excel file?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a main excel file that contains my macros. In this one I created the sheets as a template for future excel files that I need to work with and modify. Now I need to copy specific sheets and their contents to a new workbook.

I also create this workbook using VBA:

```
Sub NOUDOC()
    Dim wbNew As Workbook
    Dim data As Date
    data = Range("H3").Value
    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add()
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("C:\Users\Alina\Desktop\Carburant " & Format(data, "MMMM YYYY") & ".xlsx") 
End Sub
```

(H3 is a date that I input to filter the data I import from an SQL server)

So I want to use a VBA in my main excel file to create a new excel document that contains specific sheets from my main.

I thank you in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30393989/4539709

Comment: have you tried anything?  LIke recording yourself doing it/google?

Comment: you can use something like thisworkbook.worksheets(array(sheet1,sheet2,sheet3)).copy before saving the file.

Comment: I tried google. I used some codes I found, adapted, but it either doesn't work with my previous code, either it doesn't work as I intend to.

Comment: @Sivaprasath: it is giving me and error 9, subscript out of range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the *Array* "flavour" of `Worksheets` object:

```
Sub NOUDOC()
    Dim data As Date
    data = Range("H3").Value

    Worksheets(Array("Sh1", "Sh2", "Sh3")).Copy '<--| this will copy listed sheets into a new (and Active) workbook
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\Alina\Desktop\Carburant " & Format(data, "MMMM YYYY") & ".xlsx"
End Sub
```

Comment: i suggested the same thing. but for some reason there seems to be an script out of range error.

Comment: @SivaprasathV, you are missing quotation marks (`""`) surrounding each sheet name

Comment: WIthout this line 'Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add()' it works. I don't know why though.

Comment: Thank you very much user3598756!

Comment: @CrimsonAlchemist, You are welcome. I omitted that statement (along with the one _dimming_ `wbNew` variable) because you don't need it at all: `.Copy` method is taking care to create the new `workbook` which can be referenced to by means of `ActiveWorkbook` property of `Application` (i.e. Excel)  object

Comment: @user3598756: Hey again! Can you please tell me if I want to copy only the values, not the formulas, what I need to do? I tried with ".PasteSpecial xlPasteValues" but I cannot adapt it to my code. P.S. I also need to copy the formulas for just one sheet.

Comment: It's not a simple little tweak of my code: post a specific new question along with your code attempts

Answer (score 0):

Try the below? I haven't tried yet though.

```
Sub NOUDOC()
Dim wbTemplate as Workbook
Set wbTemplate = ActiveWorkbook
Dim wbNew As Workbook
Dim data As Date
data = Range("H3").Value
Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add()
sheet_count = 1
For Each each_sheet in wbTemplate.Sheets
    each_sheet.Copy Before:= wbNew.Sheets(sheet_count)
    sheet_count = sheet_count + 1
Next
wbNew.SaveAs ("C:\Users\Alina\Desktop\Carburant " & Format(data, "MMMM YYYY") & ".xlsx")
```