# Saving Sheet as .CSV file

Tags: vba, excel

I have to copy the data and paste it in new sheet and change the sheet name as per user requirement and save it with the same name in desired location.I have written the code and executed but I cannot find the file in specified location.Please help me on this.

```
Sub saveascsv()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim filenam As Variant
Dim saveasfile As Variant

filenam = InputBox("Enter name of the file to be saved")

Set Rng = Range("E1:H" & Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Rng.Select
Selection.Copy

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add after:=Worksheets("Part_Number")
ActiveSheet.Name = filenam
ActiveSheet.Paste

ActiveSheet.Columns("A:D").AutoFit

Application.CutCopyMode = False

saveasfile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=filenam, 
FileFilter:="CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv), *.csv", Title:="Save As")

If saveasfile <> "False" Then
   MsgBox "saveas " & filenam
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please post the code where you actually generate the csv file.

Comment: Sorry,I can"t get you.@DavidG

Comment: @DavidG-With the same code i Generate the CSV file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30393989/4539709

Comment: File Location will vary according to User So we can't to give specific location in the program@0m3r

Comment: Since you are using "Application.GetSaveAsFilename", it should prompt a dialogue box asking for file name and path. Also you have not defined any path. So, with maximum probability it will assume "My Document" as the default folder in the dialogue box. Check this location. Otherwise, you can specify the location yourself in the dialogue box.

Comment: After Selecting the Filepath will it Change to specified File path or it will be in MY DOCUMENTS itself@ArindamD

Comment: Note: There are alternate ways to save the file without the dialogue box in a pre-defined folder location.

Comment: If you select any file path, it should be saved in that location @ DINESHKUMAP

Comment: But I file is not saving in that location@ArindamD

Comment: Actually you are not saving anything. Check the response from A.S.H. Add this in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not saving anything, just getting the file's name to save and displaying a message box.

```
If saveasfile <> "False" Then
    ActiveSheet.move                     ' <-- Add this line
    ActiveSheet.SaveAs saveasfile, xlCSV ' <-- Add this line
    MsgBox "saved as " & saveasfile
End If
```

Comment: I have tried this code it works but the file name of existing workbook also converts to new name@A.S.H

Comment: Can that be fixed@A.S.H

Comment: Okay, try to add `ActiveSheet.move` before `ActiveSheet.SaveAs...`

Comment: it is not creating one extra Sheet in same worksheet@A.S.H

Comment: Is it possible to create and then save that sheet as CSV@A.S.H

Comment: if you want to keep both, `ActiveSheet.copy` instead of `ActiveSheet.move`