# How to save a macroless copy without closing the current file?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to save a copy of `ThisWorkbook` in `xlsx` while using `SaveCopyAs`. The problem is that `SaveCopyAs` saves the file as a macro enabled file, `xlsb` in my case which is not desired and while `SaveAs` does what I need, it also closes `ThisWorkbook` .

Is there an easier way to save in a format that does not support macros and without doing workarounds ?

Currently the best solution I found is the code snip below, but it's kinda finicky and it does not save the `ContentTypeProperties` that I need further on in the project, so does need to be added again.

Any ideas are appreciated, thanks!

```
Dim sPath as String

sPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sFileName & ".xlsx", 51
Application.Workbooks.Open (sPath)
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Exit Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30393989/4539709

Comment: @0m3r thanks for the quick reply, unfortunately the code in the link closes `ThisWorkbook`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Define your path `sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sFileName` without extension
2. Use `ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs sPath & ".xlsm"` to save a copy.
3. Open that copy with `Set Wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(sPath & ".xlsm")`
4. Save again without `Wb.SaveAs sPath & ".xlsx", xlOpenXMLWorkbook`
5. Close workbook `Wb.Close SaveChanges:=False`

So something like the following should work, and would keep your current code running without any re-opening side effects of the current workbook.

```
Dim sPath As String
sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sFileName 'no extension!

ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs sPath & ".xlsm"
Dim Wb As Workbook
Set Wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(sPath & ".xlsm")
Wb.SaveAs sPath & ".xlsx", xlOpenXMLWorkbook
Wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

And probably you want to delete the `xlsm` file copy

```
Kill sPath & ".xlsm"
```

You might want to make use of `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`.

Comment: So basically make a copy of the macro enabled file, open it, save the copy without any code and delete the macro enable copy ? Simple enough, thank you!

Comment: @CCM Yes, basically that's it. I think it is better than the approach in your question, because it doesn't re-open the file the code is actually running in and therefore does not interrupt the running code.