# Can You Reference/Set Variable To a Workbook Without the Extension?

Tags: excel, vba

I've tried to find the answer but didn't seem like there was one online.

Example of code:

```
dim wb_name as string
wb_name = range("A1").value & ".xlsx"
set wb = workbooks(wb_name)
```

- Is there a way to do the above without the ".xlsx" in the case the sometimes the extension changes (ex. from an old excel format to a new one)
- Is there some sort of catch all function that can interpret the different kinds of extensions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30393989/4539709

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I name a spreadsheet automatically, by referencing two cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30393659/how-do-i-name-a-spreadsheet-automatically-by-referencing-two-cells)

Comment: the above links do not apply at all to the question being. those links are for saving a workbook, not setting one as an object

Answer (score 1):

You can take a wild card approach.

```
Dim wb_name as String
wb_name = Range("A1").Value & ".****"
Set wb = Workbooks(wb_name)
```

Comment: Hey I tried this out but unfortunately it didn't work, I got a "subscript out of range" error.

Comment: wild card approach would only work if looping through workbook collections and checking for name

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the open workbooks:

```
Public sub GetWB(byval wb_name as string) as excel.workbook
Dim wbkCurr as excel.workbook 

Set getwb=nothing 
For each wbkCurr in application.workbooks
    If lower(left(wbkCurr.name, instr(wbkCurr.name,”.”))) = lcase(wb_name) then
        Set getwb = wbkCurr
    Endif
Next wbkCurr 

End function
```

Call it with set wb =getwb(wb_name)

Just check that wb isn’t still nothing before you proceed

Comment: good idea. could be enhanced to ingest an optional extension as well in case user wants to force excel version. could also be enhanced to look at all open excel instances if needed, since if workbook was opened in another instance of Excel, it would not find it.

Answer (score 0):

*You can use select case to determine the Excel version and file extension/format*

```
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        'You use Excel 97-2003
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        'You use Excel 2007-2016
        Select Case wb.FileFormat
        Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
        Case 52:
            If .HasVBProject Then
                FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
            Else
                FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            End If
        Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
        Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
        End Select
    End If
```

Here is 2 Examples

*[Use VBA SaveAs in Excel 2007-2016 - Ron de Bruin
Excel Automation](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s5/win001.htm)*

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30393989/4539709

Comment: Doesn't this code have to already have the workbook in its grasp to apply the code? This is a good method for saving, but how do you set the `Destwb` to apply the code here?