# How will I get rid of this error messages?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to ask how to get rid of this error notification? Please see picture attached.

I am using this VBA Code:

```
  Sub Sample()
'~~> Change Sheet1 to the relevant sheet
'~~> This will create a new workbook with the relevant sheet
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Fuels_Slips_Issued").Copy

'~~> Save the new workbook
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\book1.xlm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
 End Sub
```

[This a screen grab with the error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pcjwa.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30393989/4539709

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XLM is not a FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook. Omit the extenstion and let the FileFormat argument add the correct extension.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\book1", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook 'XLSX type
```

For a complete list of FileFormat types, see [xlFileFormat enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat).