# Saving as Macro enabled workbook

Tags: excel, vba

VBA fails to save as **`.xlsm`** files. 
If I save as standard **`.xls`** file entire code works, I get my files saved in the right location.

Task: 
From the current book, Loop through cells in "CategoryList" sheet and create copy of workbook and save as original (.xlsm) and return.

`ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & MyCat(i) **--> works as .xls`

Methods tried:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & MyCat(i) & ".xlsm"   
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & MyCat(i), FileFormat:=".xlsm
```

these results in a window asking to save the workbook as book.

---

My Code

```
For i = 1 To 5

  MyCategoty(i) = Sheets("CategoryList").Cells(i, 1).Value

  wb.Sheets("SheetName").Copy  

  .....my activity....

  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & MyCat(i), FileFormat:=".xlsm"   

  ActiveWorkbook.Close         

  ws.Activate                                                                     

Next i
```

---

Can someone help please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30393989/4539709

Answer (score 0):

Try fileformat like this:

```
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

Remember the open books you may have and which one has the code.

Comment: adding FileFormat:=52, worked. Thank you both.